# iPhone dev - objc_msgSend with no specific line number

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks

When I usually get runtime errors I can open up the Debugger view in XCode and see what line it occurs and fix accordingly. What do I do when there is no line number? I must have an allocation/deallocation memory error somewhere, but how do I go about finding it? The instruments tool is virtually unuseable and slow - sometimes not loading up at all. I have attached the screenshot of my Debugger window: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?1c4089f3e4.png.
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?1c4089f3e4.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?1c4089f3e4.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to that stacktrace you have an over-release. Use the Zombies instrument or set the NSZombieEnabled environment variable to YES. This will let you know what object is being over-released.

Comment: Thanks mate. I can't get that instruments thing up without it crashing! Something must have gotten corrupted somewhere.

I find the "build and analyse" option very useful. Its under the build menu.